generate number from reverse linked list
I have create a function int reverseNum(Node *head) to get number from reverse linked list.
eg. for Linked List:- 1->2->3->4 the number will be 4321.
But the program is returning 4320.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define vi vector<int>


using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;


    Node(int x,Node *n){
        data=x;
        next=n;
    }

    Node(int x){
        data=x;
        next=nullptr;
    }
};



//arr to LL
Node *arrToLL(vector<int> &arr){

    //chk if the arr is empty

    if (arr.empty()){
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node *head=new Node(arr[0]);

    Node *tmp=head;

    for (int i=1;i<arr.size();i++){
        Node *newNode=new Node(arr[i]);
        tmp->next=newNode;
        tmp=newNode;

    }


    return head;
}


//get reverse number from the LL

int reverseNum(Node *head){
    int ans=0;
    int exp=0;

    while (head!=nullptr){
        ans += (head->data * pow(10, exp)); 
        cout<<ans<<"-";
        exp++;

        head=head->next;
    }

    return ans;
}


int main(){
    vi arr1={1,2,3,4};
    vi arr2={3,5,6};

    Node *head1=arrToLL(arr1);
    Node *head2=arrToLL(arr2);

    cout<<reverseNum(head1);
    
    return 0;
}


Please read tag descriptions before using them. This has nothing to do with [tag:dsa].

the problem might be outside the function. This example is working just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/rdqqcvK7K

I cannot reproduce this either. Please provide the code that calls this function with the linked list you mention and that prints the result, so we can reproduce that issue.

Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

My gut tells me it's a case of Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?, but it's hard to tell for sure if this is the only problem.

Unrelated to your problem: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

what's your compiler and its version? Still cannot reproduce your problem even with your edited snippet.

ans += (head->data * pow(10, exp)); -- Your program is broken by using a floating point function pow.  The entire assignment you were given uses pointers and integers -- there is no need for (possibly inexact) floating point calculations to be used.

The pow function returns a double type, as it uses floating point algorithmic. This can lead to imprecisions, like occurred for the user that asked Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?.
You should not need to rely on floating point calculations for this. Instead of exp, use a variable that has the power you need, and which multiplies by 10 in each iteration:
int reverseNum(Node *head){
    int ans=0;
    int power=1; // <---

    while (head!=nullptr){
        ans += head->data * power;  // <---
        cout<<ans<<"-";
        power *= 10;  // <---
        head=head->next;
    }
    return ans;
}

Now there is no floating point processing in your code anymore and the output will be as expected.
NB: be aware that the linked list data structure could hold many more digits than int can represent. You will still get wrong results for linked lists that have like 30 digits.
